# Unable to success DELETE request from POSTMAN

Tags: postman, delete-method

Since some weeks now, I'm improving my knowledge in POSTMAN. Able to send GET, POST request, validating JSON schema, running test... and so on.

But, I'm loosing my hair trying to send DELETE request.
When you build a GET request, OAUTH1 parameters automatically sent to url parameters, but it is not the case when you select DELETE.

The problem is my API send me back "some parameter is missing" and the difference is based on these parameter in the URL.
I try to turn it to GET, and when parameters in url, get it back to DELETE, but there is issue timestamp, nonce and signature.

Rally appreciate help
Regards